# When using get_unaligned_leX() what is the purpose of adding a value to the argument?

Tags: linux-kernel, endianness

For example, in `/crypto/nhpoly1305.c`:

```
 42 static void nh_generic(const u32 *key, const u8 *message, size_t message_len,
 43                        __le64 hash[NH_NUM_PASSES])
 44 {
 45         u64 sums[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
 46 
 47         BUILD_BUG_ON(NH_PAIR_STRIDE != 2);
 48         BUILD_BUG_ON(NH_NUM_PASSES != 4);
 49 
 50         while (message_len) {
 51                 u32 m0 = get_unaligned_le32(message + 0);
 52                 u32 m1 = get_unaligned_le32(message + 4);
 53                 u32 m2 = get_unaligned_le32(message + 8);
 54                 u32 m3 = get_unaligned_le32(message + 12);
```

What is the meaning of these values added to the argument?  I assume it has something to do with bits/bytes...

Comment: Byte offset in message.

Comment: @stark how is the offset decided?

Comment: `message + 0` gets the first 4 bytes.  `message + 4` gets the next 4, etc.

Comment: @stark ah okay, gotcha.  thanks!

Comment: @stark, strictly speaking it's item offset depending on the type. Here it's byte, in some cases it may be something different.

Comment: @0andriy What other types can it depend on? (I'm assuming bit is one of them) and is the type arbitrarily decided by the person writing the code?  For example, I have ``str_count  = get_unaligned_le32(data + 8)`` and I am wondering what the purpose is of taking only the first 8 bytes(?); if it's something that was decided by the person who wrote it, or if it's dependent on some other variable that I don't know about, it's not really evident to me from the code.

Comment: You may consider `u16 *buf; u32 data; ... get_unaligned_le32(buf + <XX>);`. In this case XX will correspond to the offset (buf + 2 * XX) **bytes**. It's a C language specification (standard) which dictates this.